# Joomla External Dynamic Javascript in Module

Tags: javascript, dynamic, joomla, external

I've created an external javascript document with the extension *php* and used the line: `Header("content-type: application/x-javascript");`  in the document to make sure that it is loaded as javascript.  Then I loaded it in my module with `$doc->addScript()` but it seems I can't get at the modules parameters from the js document.

Does anyone know how I can access the module's parameters from this external script?  I've tried print_r'ing the _GET and _POST and there is nothing there.

Does anyone have a clue how to get these params in an externally loaded script/stylesheet?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the parameters to session or cookie or explicitly hand them over:

the latter would require you to invoke your external module like :

```
$doc->addScript("path/to/your/js.php?option1=$value1&amp;option2=$value2");
```

I hope you get the idea.